# How to store values that result from executing an app using system(" ") on ruby on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using `system(" ")` on the rails console to execute an application that takes inside a file, processes it and outputs another file.

The application also logs statistics for said file on the terminal before closing.

My objective is to save those logged statistics as variables inside rails, although I'm not exactly sure how I can do that.

How can I save the logged statistics inside rails variables?

Comment: [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `system` method is the best method to use here, as I think this would either return `true` or `false`. However to get back the value, you should try to use the `backticks`

```
statistics = `method to call on computer`
```

let me know if that works

Comment: This allowed me to save all the console log on a variable and now I can use a string function to find the relevant data, thank you.